# Google map simple map

Tags: google-maps

I need to put a map on a website but the clients doesn't want anything but a simple outline of the United States.  I used google maps styling wizard but still wasn't able to get just the outline.  The reason I want to use google maps is I need to dynamically place markers using the latitude and longitude coordinates.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pretty sure you can't do this with Google Maps. You may have better luck with Leaflet:

> Leaflet is a modern, lightweight open-source JavaScript library for interactive maps for desktop and mobile web browsers, developed by CloudMade to form the core of its next generation JavaScript API. Weighting just about 21kb of gzipped JS code, it still has all the features you will ever need for you web mapping needs while providing a fast, smooth, pleasant user experience.
>
> http://leaflet.cloudmade.com/

Just use a single map image with the outline you want. If you need to generate the image yourself and really customize the map, you'll want to combine Leaflet with a few tiles generated with Mapnik, OpenStreetMap data (*not* the whole-world dataset probably), and possssibly TileCache.

> http://tilecache.org/
>
> http://mapnik.org/
>
> http://planet.openstreetmap.org/